# How do I add a link in a Google Sheets to a specific paragraph or header in a Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, links

How do I add a link in a Google spreadsheet to a specific paragraph or header in a Google document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a link in a Google Spreadsheet you can use the formula `=HYPERLINK( "www.google.com" ; "Search Google" )`.

For that link to point to a specific position in a Google Doc, use the Headings feature and create a **Table of contents**, from which you can take the anchor link to that specific part of the document.

To add a table of contents follow these steps:

1. Add headings to your document by clicking **Format** > **Paragraph styles** in the toolbar, and selecting a heading.
2. Click **Table of contents** from the **Insert** menu. The table of contents appears wherever you've clicked in the document, so make sure you place your cursor where you want to add the table of contents. If you need to move the table of contents, select it as you would select text and either move it with your cursor or cut it and paste it.
3. You can continue to add headings to your document or change current headings. However, if you'd like a change to become part of the table of contents, you need to click first the table and then the **Update now** button.
4. Each item in your table of contents links to the titled sections of your document that use the heading styles (that you added in step 1 above).

From the man page: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106342

So, take the document's link and add to it the anchor from the respective heading.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b4Jq5UtuhzIG-NuPJiYh6ojR8GtL7dRKyAhcWdnUPSI/edit?hl=en_GB&pli=1#heading=h.hmr6expwb2i7) is a document I've created, that opens to a specific point.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the URL of a header without creating a Table of Contents.

Put the cursor on the header itself, then look at the address bar of your browser.  It should change to update the fragment (hash - #) at the end like `#heading=h.abc32def4` -- this should correspond to the link created in the Table of Contents.  Copy that entire url and use as suggested by [the accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/18082).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a **Bookmark**. From the doc,

> Insert > Bookmark

You can use the link generated for the bookmark in a google sheet.

More info can be found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).